# Debian fails to reconnect to LAN after router reboot

Tags: debian, networkmanager, ethernet

When I reboot my router, for whatever reason, my PC seems to get stuck in a loop. It keeps attempting to reconnect but always fails. The only solution seems to be either to reboot the computer or pull the ethernet cable out of it for a few seconds (the second method sometimes doesn't work on the first attempt, thus it has to be repeated). After that everything is fine.

I've set a static IP to my PC in the router settings.

Basic info:

OS: Debian 11 Bullseye

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux Simon-s-PC 5.7.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.6-1 (2020-06-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bsh
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
05:01.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

I believe this is the important part of `journalctl` output, full log [here](https://paste.debian.net/1155208/):

```bsh
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6381] device (enp6s0): carrier: link connected
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6386] device (enp6s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC kernel: alx 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: NIC Up: 10 Mbps Full
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6403] policy: auto-activating connection 'New 802-3-ethernet connection' (2fffd0a4-184a-4d0e-8904-3096d4fa30a0)
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6418] device (enp6s0): Activation: starting connection 'New 802-3-ethernet connection' (2fffd0a4-184a-4d0e-8904-3096d4fa3>
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6419] device (enp6s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6421] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <warn>  [1593956136.6422] device (enp6s0): set-link: failure to set link negotiation
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6422] device (enp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6426] device (enp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956136.6428] dhcp4 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp6s0.IPv6 with address fe80::7044:872d:a7f3:f654.
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: New relevant interface enp6s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 05 15:35:36 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: Registering new address record for fe80::7044:872d:a7f3:f654 on enp6s0.*.
Jul 05 15:35:38 Simon-s-PC kernel: alx 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: Link Down
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956144.6571] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956144.6807] dhcp4 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956144.6808] dhcp4 (enp6s0): state changed unknown -> done
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7044:872d:a7f3:f654 on enp6s0.
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1593956144.6898] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp6s0.IPv6 with address fe80::7044:872d:a7f3:f654.
Jul 05 15:35:44 Simon-s-PC avahi-daemon[803]: Interface enp6s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

Is there anything I could do to fix this?

Comment: You could be encountering "Speed Renegotiation", where your NIC and the router's NIC can't agree on a speed. `service NetworkManager restart` might help.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, sadly it didn't work. Thank you anyhow. I also realized that pulling the ethernet cable out off my PC works only some of the time. I also forgot to mention that I have set a static IP to my PC in the router settings. I've added the missing things into my question.